# How to retrieve the parameters calculated and used by ImageAdjust?

Tags: image-processing, implementation-details

When `ImageAdjust` is called with an image, i.e. with one parameter, it returns an automatically adjusted `Image`.  I would like to retrieve the `{contrast, brightness, gamma}` values `ImageAdjust` has calculated and use them as starting points for a following interactive manipulation of these value using `ImageAdjust[img, {contrast, brightness, gamma}]`, i.e. with four parameters.

An obvious solution is to perform an image histogram equalization and calculate `{contrast, brightness, gamma}`.  However, since ***Mathematica*** provides the solution somewhere in its code and I intend to continue using `ImageAdjust` I would rather conform with the already implemented algorithm.

Hence, my questions is: How do I retrieve the parameters calculated and used by `ImageAdjust` when it runs automatically?

Comment: A duplicate question: [(92287)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92287/280).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

---

**Major update at the bottom**. First part may be obsolete.

---

A brute force approach:

Define a function that provides a measure of the difference between the automatically adjusted image and an image with given contrast, brightness and gamma adjustments (for now, this only works for images that are made of a raster of color triplets):

```
ClearAll[f];
f[c_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, γ_?NumericQ, im_Image] := 
    Total[Map[#.# &, ImageData@ImageAdjust[im] - ImageData@ImageAdjust[im, {c, b, γ}], {2}], 2]
```

Get an image:

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAaCm.png"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now minimize the image differences:

```
adj = FindMinimum[f[c, b, γ, img], {{c, 0.1, 0, -1, 1}, {b, 0.1, 0, -1, 1}, {γ, 1.1, 1, 0.1, 3}}]
```

> {14.19915417, {c -> -0.06143890985, b -> 0.09520280553, γ -> 1.094933574}}

Comparison of original image and automatically adjusted image:

```
Row[{img, ImageReflect[ImageAdjust[img], Left -> Right], img}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comparison of the semi-automatically adjusted image and fully automatically adjusted image:

```
Row[{ImageAdjust[img, {c, b, γ} /. adj[[2]]],
     ImageReflect[ImageAdjust[img], Left -> Right], 
     ImageAdjust[img, {c, b, γ} /. adj[[2]]]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The differences are small:

```
ImageSubtract[ImageAdjust[img, {c, b, γ} /. adj[[2]]], ImageAdjust[img]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And 'small' is this:

```
ImageSubtract[ImageAdjust[img, {c, b, γ} /. adj[[2]]], ImageAdjust[img]] // ImageData // Max
```

> 0.0431372549

Using `ImageAdjust` itself to enhance those differences:

```
ImageSubtract[ImageAdjust[img, {c, b, γ} /. adj[[2]]], ImageAdjust[img]] // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not quite an exact match but close.

---

**EDIT**

Originally, I believed that `ImageAdjust` does a simple histogram stretch, scaling the maximum pixel value to 1 and the minimum to 0, basically this:

```
imgd = img // ImageData;
min = Min[imgd];
max = Max[imgd];
Rescale[imgd, {min, max}, {0, 1}]
```

But that simply didn't work out. If I use the measure introduced in the beginning to determine the difference between the {c,b,γ}-adjusted pictures and the automatically `ImageAdjusted` pictures on the one hand and the rescaled pictures and the automatically `ImageAdjusted` pictures on the other hand, the {c,b,γ} seems to be better 4 out of the 5 test images I used it on.

```
(
   img = #;
   imgd = img // ImageData;
   min = Min[imgd];
   max = Max[imgd];
   adj = FindMinimum[f[c, b, γ, img], 
                     {{c, 0.1, 0, -1, 1}, {b, 0.1, 0, -1, 1}, {γ, 1.1, 1, 0.1, 3}}];
   {Total[Map[#.# &,
          ImageData@ImageAdjust[img]-ImageData@ImageAdjust[img, {c, b, γ} /. adj[[2]]], {2}],
      2],
    Total[Map[#.# &, ImageData@ImageAdjust[img]-Rescale[imgd, {min, max}, {0, 1}], {2}], 2]
    }
   ) & /@ { ...images...}
```

For the five pictures on the `ImageAdjust` doc page I get:

> {{50.5394233, 81.76899059}, {14.19915417, 14.46839005}, {30.34660515, 
>     46.0902785}, {6.459238754, 2.528418174}, {537.6580546, 1011.243348}}

It seems that `ImageAdjust` does more than a simple stretching of the values. It probably uses *histogram equalization*, which linearizes the cumulative distribution function of the pixel intensity values. This is a rather non-linear transformation. It probably requires a transformation to another color space first, to separate color values from luminance values (CIELab for instance). The transformation will then be done on the luminance component only after which an inverse color space transformation occurs.

---

**Yet another edit**

Trying to test the hypothesis *Mathematica* is using histogram equalization.

Load an image and turn it into grayscale (we won't do this colorspace hence and forth stuff here):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGMge.png"]
imgG = ImageData[ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Do histogram equalization:

```
ClearAll[cdf];
SetAttributes[cdf, Listable]
Scan[(cdf[#[[1]]] = #[[2]]) &,
     Transpose[MapAt[Accumulate, Transpose[Sort@Tally[Flatten[imgG]]], 2]]]
imgH = (cdf[imgG] - cdf[Min[imgG]])/(Times @@ ImageDimensions[img] - cdf[Min[imgG]]);
```

Accumulated counts before equalization:

```
ListPlot@Transpose[MapAt[Accumulate, Transpose[Sort@Tally[Flatten[imgG]]], 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Accumulated counts after equalization:

```
ListPlot@Transpose[MapAt[Accumulate, Transpose[Sort@Tally[Flatten[imgH]]], 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Image comparisons:

Original grayscale image:

```
imgG // Image
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Automatically adjusted image:

```
imgG // Image // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Histogram equalized image:

```
imgH // Image
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly, `ImageAdjust` does not do a histogram equalization.

---

**Final edit**

For grayscale images at least, Mathematica seems to do a simple rescaling after all. The rescaling I used above used the minimum and maximum values measured over *all color channels*. In a grayscale image, rescaling with

```
Rescale[imgG, {Min[imgG], Max[imgG]}, {0, 1}]
```

yields an image that is virtually identical to the adjusted image:

```
(imgG // Image // ImageAdjust // ImageData) - 
 Rescale[imgG, {Min[imgG], Max[imgG]}, {0, 1}] // Abs // Max
```

> 2.220446049*10^-16

So, conclusion: there are no {c, b, γ} parameters to be estimated
because `ImageAdjust`, called without additional parameters, doesn't use
them.

Comment: +1 Cool question & solution ;) Nice to see clean convergence in 3-parameters space.

Comment: Here, one could use `FindArgMin[]` instead of `FindMinimum[]`, since we're only interested in the parameters (as opposed to the minimum value.)

Comment: Thank you very much.  That is neat, is very well presented and works well. But a) it is not really what I asked for and b) it is fairly slow.  The actual issue is, the values have already been calculated by ImageAdjust and I wonder if there isn't a simple way to get them with the adjusted image.

Comment: @ErnstStelzer Please see my final edit: there seem to be no parameters to be estimated after all.

Comment: @ErnstStelzer Sjoerd conclusions is with agreement with the fact Matthias stated in his answer. Indeed, no parameters to estimate.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answers.  I conclude the question as answered.  Maybe one could add another parameter to ImageAdjust in a future 9.x version such as {img, {c, b, gamma}} = ImageAdjust[..., "ReturnParameters"].

Comment: @Sjoerd wouldn't the people  at WRI tell us what it actually do? Why do we need to reverse engineer  what ought to be a documented process? After all, scientifically we need to know what it does (if not how)?

Comment: @chris I agree that some (many?) methods could have been documented more extensively. In this case, one could say that it *was* documented: "ImageAdjust[image] 
adjusts the levels in image, rescaling them to cover the range 0 to 1." It doesn't spell out how color images are treated though.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries For RGB images, each R, G, B channel is processed independently.

Answer (score 8):

With only one argument, `ImageAdjust[img]` performs histogram stretching, ie. pixel values, which run from `min` to `max` in `img`, are rescaled so they run from 0 to 1 in the ouput image.

The setting `{contrast, brightness, gamma} = {0, 0, 1}` does not change anything:
`ImageAdjust[img, {0, 0, 1}] === img` gives `True`.