# Which values did ImageAdjust choose?

Tags: image-processing, image

I have a picture obtained from a camera in an experiment. It's a *.dat* file, contains only numbers. I can re-create the image by importing it as *data* and using the `Image[*data*]` command.

However, I need to use `ImageAdjust[Image[data]]` to make something visible. Since I want to perform *the same adjustment* on several pictures, I need to know exactly which values [`ImageAdjust`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAdjust.html) chooses for brightness, contrast, etc.

How to find out?

Comment: According to the documentation `ImageAdjust[Image[data]]` is equivalent to `Image[Rescale[data]]`. If you want the same adjustment you'll have to specify it explicitly.

Comment: I don't see where it says it is equivalent to `Rescale`, but it is clearly not true for multi channel images.  For color images `ImageAdjust` works independently on each channel while `Rescale` applies a single transformation to the whole data array.   Oddly `ImageAdjust` does not provide options to manually specify each channel range, so you cant use it directly even if you know the transform the auto setting used.

Comment: MikeLimaOscars answer wasn't directly what I wanted, but playing around with Rescale definitively got me some steps further! Thanks!

Comment: A duplicate question: [(14956)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14956/280).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a look at the default behavior of `ImageAdjust` on a color image:

```
 img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
 adj = ImageAdjust@img;
 Column[ Table[
   inout  = 
     Transpose@(Flatten[ImageData@ColorSeparate[#][[channel]], 1] & /@
          {img, adj});
   fit = LinearModelFit[ inout , x , x];
   Row[{fit, 
      Show[{Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red],
      ListPlot[inout]},
         ImageSize -> 300]
          }] , {channel, 3}]]
```

[image]

What you see is a simple linear transform on each channel. 
We could have got at those numbers just by looking at the data range for each channel:

```
Table[
   range = Sort[
      Flatten[ImageData@ColorSeparate[img][[channel]], 1]][[{1, -1}]];
     ({range[[1]] # , -#} &@ 1/(Subtract @@ range)) , {channel, 3}]
```

> {{-0.268657, 1.26866}, {-0.0122449, 1.04082}, {-0.0368664, 1.17512}}

From this I suppose the answer to the question should be to first pass through all the images and find the absolute range over all the images for each channel, then use `ImageApply` to do the scaling.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this one is exactly what I searched.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming all your images are the same size and channel depth you can create a per pixel, per channel scale factor base on what `ImageAdjust` has done and multiply each image by it.

```
adjustImages[keyImage_, images_] := 
 With[{scaleFactor = Flatten@ImageData@ImageAdjust@keyImage/Flatten@ImageData@keyImage}, 
  Image@ArrayReshape[scaleFactor Flatten@ImageData@#,
    Dimensions@ImageData@keyImage]&/@images]
```

And apply so:

```
adjustImages[kim,{im1,im1,im3,...,imn}]
```

You may want to decide what the the result should be if rescaling using the key image pushes values beyond the normal range and saturates.

It may also be worth exploring what it actually is you want to adjust in the images to improve performance on whatever pipeline follows, rather than trusting `ImageAdjust` to optimise things to your requirements.

Comment: `ImageAdjust` actually does a linear transform, so properly you need to fit to a `scale + offset` form. (this will work if keyimage has at least one completely black pixel.. )

Answer (score 3):

Under the "Properties & Relations" on the Documentation page for `ImageAdjust` [we read](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAdjust.html#1617530736):

> `ImageAdjust[image]` is equivalent to `ImageAdjust[image,{0,0,1},{min,max},{0,1}]` where `{min,max}` is the channel-wise pixel ranges in image:

```
ImageAdjust[img] == 
 ImageAdjust[img, {0, 0, 1}, ImageMeasurements[img, {"Min", "Max"}], {0, 1}]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

So `ImageAdjust[img]` works channel-wise and by default simply rescales channel values on the base of `MinMax` ranges returned by `ImageMeasurements`.

Note however that due to a [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92461/280) in `ImageAdjust` currently [we have to unpack](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92461/imageadjust-documentation-issues/92465#comment251357_92465) the output of `ImageMeasurements` manually:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}];
ImageAdjust[img] === 
 ImageAdjust[img, {0, 0, 1}, List @@@ ImageMeasurements[img, {"Min", "Max"}], {0, 1}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

The output of `ImageMeasurements` is just `Transpose` of `MinMax` applied separately to each channel:

```
Transpose[MinMax /@ ImageData[img, Interleaving -> False]] == 
 ImageMeasurements[img, {"Min", "Max"}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

We can also understand the default behavior of `ImageAdjust[img]` as applying `Rescale` separately to each channel:

```
data = ImageData[img, Interleaving -> False];
res1 = ImageAdjust[Image[data, Interleaving -> False]]; 
res2 = Image[Rescale /@ data, Interleaving -> False];
Max@Abs[ImageData[res1] - ImageData[res2]]
```

> ```
> 1.11022*10^-16
> ```

It is worth to note here that `ImageAdjust` always returns an image with the same `ImageType` as the original image:

```
ImageType@ImageAdjust@Image[img, #] & /@ {"Bit", "Byte", "Bit16", "Real32", "Real"}
```

> ```
> {"Bit", "Byte", "Bit16", "Real32", "Real"}
> ```

This explains significant difference which we get in the cases like the following (caused by rounding off the channel values in the case of the `"Byte"` image):

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}];
res1 = ImageAdjust[img];
ImageType[res1]
res2 = ImageAdjust[Image[img, "Real"]];
ImageType[res2]
Max@Abs[ImageData[res1] - ImageData[res2]]
```

> ```
> "Byte"
>
> "Real"
>
> 0.0019607843137254832`
> ```