# ImageAdjust Documentation issues

Tags: bugs, image-processing, documentation

**Bug in `ImageAdjust` introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and fixed in 11.0**

**Documentation bug for `ImageAdjust`  introduced in 8 or earlier and fixed in 11.1.0**

<sup>In version 11.1.0 the first statement under "Properties & Relations" reads as  (emphasized words are absent in version 11.0.1): "**For grayscale images,** `ImageAdjust[Image[data]]` is equivalent to `Image[Rescale[data]]`".</sup>

---

[A recent thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92287/280) raised several concerns regarding the Documentation page for `ImageAdjust`.

---

[**The first issue**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92287/which-values-did-imageadjust-choose#comment250944_92287) is related to the first statement under the "Properties & Relations" [on the Documentation page for `ImageAdjust`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAdjust.html#381965980):

> `ImageAdjust[Image[data]]` is equivalent to `Image[Rescale[data]]`.

This statement is incorrect for two reasons:

1. As [george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) correctly [notes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92287/which-values-did-imageadjust-choose#comment250944_92287), "For color images `ImageAdjust` works independently on each channel while `Rescale` applies a single transformation to the whole data array."
2. Actually even for single-channel images `Image[Rescale[data]]` produces slightly different image as it is clear from the example provided:

   ```
   data = GaborMatrix[100, {.1, .1}];
   res1 = ImageAdjust[Image[data]];
   res2 = Image[Rescale[data]];
   Max[ImageData[res1] - ImageData[res2]]
   ```

   > ```
   > 2.77556*10^-17
   > ```

   From the other hand, if we try to use [the code for the second statement](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAdjust.html#1617530736) under the "Properties & Relations" for the above single-channel image we obtain exactly identical image:

   ```
   ImageAdjust[Image[data]] == 
    ImageAdjust[Image[data], {0, 0, 1}, 
     ImageMeasurements[Image[data], {"Min", "Max"}], {0, 1}]
   ```

   > ```
   > True
   > ```

From the above it is clear that for single-channel images the correct statement should be: "`ImageAdjust[Image[data]]` is equivalent to `ImageAdjust[Image[data], {0, 0, 1}, ImageMeasurements[Image[data], {"Min", "Max"}], {0, 1}]`."

---

**The second issue** is related to the above-mentioned [code for the second statement](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAdjust.html#1617530736) under the "Properties & Relations". This code simply does not work with the provided color image and produces error (checked with version 10.2 on Windows 7 x64):

[image: screenshot]

Does it mean that `ImageAdjust` does not allow to specify separate range for each channel as [george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) [states in the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92287/which-values-did-imageadjust-choose#comment250944_92287)? In this case, then we have a bug in the Documentation (see the statement on the above screenshot). An alternative is that we have a bug in `ImageAdjust`.

What do you think about the first issue? Is it a Documentation bug?

Answer (score 4):

This is interesting. I have two comments that grew too long for the comment box, so I'll post them here instead.

1. Is it possible that the discrepancy in your point (2) is only due to roundoff error? After all the difference is less than `$MachineEpsilon`.
2. I made the following weird discovery: if you calculate the result of the `ImageMeasurements` expression, then copy the numerical result inside the `ImageAdjust` expression, it will work; if you leave the ImageMeasurements inside the `ImageAdjust`, or even if you assign that value to a variable first, it will not work anymore!

Here is what I mean. I am using the image from the docs, which I also [uploaded here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNOOh.jpg) for convenience:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
imgmeas = ImageMeasurements[img, {"Min", "Max"}]
(* Out: {{0.00784314, 0.0627451, 0.117647}, {0.882353, 0.898039, 0.984314}} *)

ImageAdjust[
 img,
 {0, 0, 1},
 {{0.00784314, 0.0627451, 0.117647}, {0.882353, 0.898039, 0.984314}},
 {0, 1}
]

ImageMeasurements[%, {"Min", "Max"}]
```

[image: it worked]

```
(* Out: {{0., 0., 0.}, {1., 1., 1.}} *)
```

---

Compare the above to what happens when you use the saved values from `imgmeas`:

```
ImageAdjust[
 img,
 {0, 0, 1},
 imgmeas,
 {0, 1}
]
```

[image: does not work]

I'm afraid that I don't have an explanation of what is going on here, unless it's a problem within `ImageAdjust`. What are we missing?

Comment: Surprisingly, it also works if we pack or unpack the output of `ImageMeasurements`: ``ImageAdjust[img, {0, 0, 1}, 
 Developer`ToPackedArray@ImageMeasurements[img, {"Min", "Max"}], {0, 1}]`` works and ``ImageAdjust[img, {0, 0, 1}, 
 Developer`FromPackedArray@ImageMeasurements[img, {"Min", "Max"}], {0, 1}]`` works too!

Comment: It seems that the reason for the problem is that `ImageMeasurements` returns a `List` of packed arrays: ``Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ ImageMeasurements[img, {"Min", "Max"}]`` returns `{True, True}`, while the upper level is not packed: ``Developer`PackedArrayQ@ImageMeasurements[img, {"Min", "Max"}]`` returns `False`.

Comment: So another workaround is to apply `List` on the `Level` `1` for unpacking the packed lists: `ImageAdjust[img, {0, 0, 1}, List @@@ ImageMeasurements[img, {"Min", "Max"}], {0, 1}]` works.

Comment: I have checked it in version 8.0.4 and it has the same bug in `ImageAdjust`: ``ImageAdjust[img,{0,0,1},Developer`ToPackedArray/@{{0.007,0.06,0.1},{0.8,0.8,0.9}},{0,1}]`` produces the same error as in version 10.

Comment: For the color image we obtain exactly identical image with the above workaround: ``ImageAdjust[img]===ImageAdjust[img,{0,0,1},List@@@ImageMeasurements[img,{"Min","Max"}],{0,1}]`` returns `True`. So this Documentation statement is correct.

Comment: @Alexey That's fascinating. I wonder when the behavior changed, and why `ImageMeasurements` returns a packed array in the first place, and also why that would be a problem within `ImageAdjust`, unless it somehow conflicts with some argument checking. I thought that an array's packed / unpacked state was essentially transparent to the user and to (most?) functions.

Comment: I suppose it is a bug in argument checking inside of `ImageAdjust`.